# ImportError: No module named social_django.middleware.in import_module __import__(name)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Hello I am trying to execute a project that is made in django 1.10.8 and pyhon 2.7 and the python_social_auth library. When I try to execute the project I get the following error.I hope you can help me

```
manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f4b908eb488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 39, in inner_run
    http_consumer=self.get_consumer(*args, **options),
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in get_consumer
    return StaticFilesConsumer()
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.handler = self.handler_class()
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__init__()
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named social_django.middleware
```

Comment: Python 2.7 is end-of-life.   Django 1.10 has been end-of-life for nearly 5 years.    You should retire this project.  (Or port it to Python 3.x / Django 3.1.)

Comment: Having said that, there is insufficient information to know what you might have done wrong.  Have you read / followed the instructions in https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The Python executable you use to run the application doesn't have social_django installed. You can verify this by running these commands:

**python manage.py shell**

**import social_django**

This will give you an error, for the same reason.

You can install it with:

**pip install social-auth-app-django**